# Do I use "is" or "are" in these situations?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Suppose I want to describe "work" or types of work on a school. 
Do I use "is" or "are" in these situations?

1. > The proposed renovation and rehabilitation of the school
   > **is** subject to strict design limitations.

   or

   > The proposed renovation and rehabilitation of the school
   > **are** subject to strict design limitations.

---

2. > The proposed rehabilitation and revitalization work on the school
   > **is** subject to strict design limitations.

   or

   > The proposed rehabilitation and revitalization work on the school
   > **are** subject to strict design limitations.

---

I think that terms like "rehabilitation", "revitalization", "construction"
and similar "-ion" words are uncountable
and therefore take a singular verb. 
When they are joined with an "and",
I suppose the plural verb makes more sense,
but it doesn't sound "right." 
If they are replaced with countable (non-abstract) nouns
such as "door" or "window", it's much easier:

> The proposed door and window of the school
> **are** subject to strict design limitations.

I'm actually even more interested in the answer to my second example –
"rehabilitation and revitalization **work** at the school **is/are**" –
because I find it a bit more challenging. 
"Work" is also uncountable – is "rehabilitation and revitalization"
just an adjective phrase that modifies "work"
or is [are] "rehabilitation work" and "revitalization work" separate things,
so that when they are joined by "and" they become plural subjects?

Comment: Welcome! Just to show that you've done some initial thought or research, what do you think about the options?

Comment: Yes, with rather fuzzy coordinations, and the availability of logical as well as formal concord, things can get tricky. In (2), there's also the problem of deciding between [A and B][work] and [A] and [B work]. I'd choose 'is' in (1) (cf Bacon and eggs is my favourite breakfast; Health and safety is our primary concern ...) but not worry at all if someone else preferred 'are' (in your case!) // In (2), the ambiguity complicates. Either verb form is possible.